# Moving all files with a certain extension to another folder with a bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am making a bat file which will change the extension then move it to another folder

I have managed to do the replace part like so:

```
ren *.txt *.jpg
```

However I would like to move all .jpg file without moving the .bat file that renamed them.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you consider using `move`?

Comment: Can you use move for only certain file types?

Comment: Would I have suggested it if you couldn't? :-) See my answer.

Comment: Just to be sure, you *are aware* that simply renaming a text (.txt) file to a JPEG (.jpg) extension does **not** convert that text file into a picture. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [move](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772528%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

```
ren *.txt *.jpg
move *.jpg \NewDestination
```

Of course, you should replace `\NewDestination` with the actual path to the folder on your system where you want the files to be moved.

I find the [TechNet Command Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340%28WS.10%29.aspx) a useful place to have bookmarked.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like:

```
move dir1\*.jpg dir2\...
```